# calculate the following limit: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^5}{\sin^3(x) \cdot \tan(x^2)}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to solve following statement

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^5}{\sin^3(x) \cdot \tan(x^2)}$$

I tried using rule of l‘Hospital. Made 2 derivatives but didn’t got „rid“ of the sinus in the term turning the whole term 0. I found some statements online to replace $\sin^3(x)$ with $x^3$ and $\tan(x^2)$ with $x^2$
Which would lead to:

$\frac {x^5}{x^3 \cdot x^2}$ which equals $1$. Which would be the correct solution if one draws the graph. But how would one solve it without this rule.

Comment: Hint: if they exist, the product of the limits is equal to the limit of the product.

Comment: So just look at the limits of every single term?

Comment: Basically, you probably know the limit of $\sin(x)/x $ as $x$ goes to 0, so you have dealt with 3/5 of the expression already.

Comment: Yes I tried it right now but I couldn’t figure it how this can help me in particularly

Comment: Ok I tried doing it and looking through the single products getting $cos^3(x)+tan^2(x^2)cos^3(x) / 2x$

Comment: Ok I made it thank you a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just used L'Hopital's rule, you would have to use it 5 times in a row to escape the $0/0$ form. A smarter way would be to break it into pieces:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^5}{\sin^3(x)\cdot\tan(x^2)}
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3}{\sin^3(x)} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\tan(x^2)}
= \left(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^3 \cdot \lim_{u\to0} \frac{u}{\tan u} = 1^3 \cdot 1 = 1.
$$

The last two steps are just the reciprocals of the limits defining the derivatives of $\sin$ and $\tan$, i.e.,

$$
    \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{u}{\tan u} = \frac{1}{\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{\tan(u) - \tan(0)}{u}} = \frac{1}{\sec^2(0)} = 1,
$$
and the corrseponding argument for $\frac{x}{\sin x}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!